# Navbar in Twitter Bootstrap resize when there is some available space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I'm having the code in Bootstrap RC1:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="hand navbar-brand"style="font-family:'Yanone Kaffeesatz';font-size:30px">
            TITLE
        </span>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#asd"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse bs-navbar-collapse"id="asd">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a class="hand">Menu1Menu1</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"id="navbarNuevo">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown"class="dropdown-toggle hand">Menu2Menu2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:200px;"placeholder="">
                <button class="btn btn-warning">Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That looks like:

[image: navbar]

When I resize it:

[image: navbar resized]

But when a I resize just a bit more, I get a problem:

[navbar problem http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/6594/q56j.png](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/6594/q56j.png)

And there's still available space!

This is the biggest problem I'm having at the moment. But, once solved, I need another help. How can I do for always having the navbar centered on the screen? When the navbar is collapsed there are no problems and the title centered itself. But as you can see in the second image, the title is pulled to the left. Well, thank you very much for at least have read the question.

Comment: What's happening is that you're reaching a breakpoint in the media queries where the `.container` resizes, you may want to extend the max-width of the container overwriting this rule `@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
max-width: 728px;
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
     <div class="container">
     <div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span10 offset1">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <span class="hand navbar-brand"style="font-family:'Yanone Kaffeesatz';font-size:30px">
                TITLE
            </span>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#asd"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse bs-navbar-collapse"id="asd">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a class="hand">Menu1Menu1</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"id="navbarNuevo">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown"class="dropdown-toggle hand">Menu2Menu2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:200px;"placeholder="">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning">Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```